# SQL: last 6 months data, Different results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, C#.NET4.5, Winforms.

I've been stuck on this for a while.

I have two queries, the 1st:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Last6MonthSales]
AS
   DELETE FROM dbo.Sales6months

   INSERT INTO dbo.Sales6months
     SELECT Part, SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as qty
     FROM dbo.IHeads
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Ilines ON dbo.Iheads.document = dbo.Ilines.document
     WHERE dbo.IHeads.prefix = 'i'
       AND month([ILines].[datetime]) > month(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, (SELECT max([DATETIME]) FROM ILines) ) - 6, 0)) 
       AND year([ILines].[datetime]) > year(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, (SELECT max([DATETIME]) FROM ILines) ) - 6, 0))
```

This one as you can tell gets me the last 6 months Sales as a **count** for **each part** number.

The next one is my second query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[q6MonthsHistory]
   @part as varchar(55),
   @time as int
AS
   SELECT SUM(Qty) as qty 
   FROM 
      ilines 
   RIGHT JOIN
      IHeads ON dbo.Iheads.document = dbo.Ilines.document
   WHERE 
      Part = @part 
      AND month(ilines.[datetime]) = month(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, (SELECT max([DATETIME]) FROM ILines)) - @time, 0)) 
      AND year(ilines.[datetime]) = year(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, (SELECT max([DATETIME]) FROM ILines)) - @time, 0))
```

As you can see this one is to get the **break down** over the last 6months, **@time** is an **int** that will have **0,1,2,3,4,5**.

Now when I get the results back, for the **1st** query on a part number lets say **"test part"**.

I get **854** as the total.

When I run the **second** query I get the **break down** I get the following results:

```
136, 142, 150, 144, 105, 149 = *826*
```

So from the same data source I'm getting **two different results**. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, in which query, or even both queries?

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Variable `@time` is having value 0 to 5 in the 2 query while in the 1 query you have hard coded the value to 6. I think so you should use 1 to 6 ...

Comment: suprisingly i didnt notice that, whats more suprising it hasnt changed the result.....thats very strange

Comment: Are you having sales in the future? What does `SELECT max([DATETIME]) FROM ILines` return?

Comment: no mate, Table wasnt updating me with new results, i didnt notice that i was no longer getting any data due to month>month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was two reasons, the first was picked up by @meherzad I had 1st -6 then i had 0-5 in 2nd query.

Then the other reason was the first query wasn't actually updating my table, any wasnt getting an results, this was due too month() > month() not working, so i removed this, it now apears to be working.

thanks guys!